# JIT hot recompilation

Tags: .net, performance, compiler-construction, clr, jit

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133336/hot-recompilation-for-c), but differ, because i don't ask about EditAndContinue.

I've readed that a hot recompilation exists. I mean for example we have a code like this

```
if (a > 0 && b >0 && c > 0 && d > 0)
```

we suppose that we have an environment (CLR, for example) that monitoring executable and launch JIT. So this environment see that condition `d > 0` come rare (we dunno actual values of `a b c` or `d` while compiling, we can only collect some statistics in runtime). So it can recompile it like this

```
if (d > 0 && a > 0 && b >0 && c > 0)
```

so we got an optimization due to the least likely condition checked first. So how this **hot recompilation** is actualy named? How and where does it works?

Comment: Are you looking for an existing optimization framework that does it or checking how to implement this kind of optimization?

Comment: This is a question about the Great White Yeti, it too has a name but doesn't actually exist.  Branch prediction is a processor feature.

Comment: The JIT does not insert profiling instrumentation as of .NET 4.5, so it cannot know how often individual branches are taken. This feature is not in the CLR at the moment. In fact the JIT is pretty poor in general. It is fast, and it has no high-quality mode.

Comment: This feautre defenitly exists, i know that not in .Net, but somewhere. And i forgot where i saw it :(

Comment: @Hans: Sometimes you have great answers, and sometimes you act like a troll.  There's a limit to how much reordering can be done in software, and how much can be done in hardware (by the processor), and the limit for software is *much* larger.  This is a useful feature for a JIT to have, and some JIT compilers for non-Microsoft platforms actually do online profile-guided recompilation.  In fact, I suspect that Microsoft AOT compilers performing profile-guided optimization do it as well or soon will.

Comment: "Sometimes you have great answers, and sometimes you act like a troll." - what do you mean? I'm not a troll :( I just want to understand. And your comment seems to be an answer...

Comment: Alex, the troll remark wasn't directed at you, but at @HansPassant.

Answer (score 0):

Could be called [Branch Reordering](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53804).

GCC also seems to support a similar [branch profiling option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), which might help you track down the real name.

```
-fbranch-probabilities
   After running a program compiled with -fprofile-arcs
   (see Options for Debugging Your Program or gcc), you can compile it a second
   time using -fbranch-probabilities, to improve optimizations based on the number
   of times each branch was taken. When a program compiled with -fprofile-arcs
   exits, it saves arc execution counts to a file called sourcename.gcda for each
   source file. The information in this data file is very dependent on the
   structure of the generated code, so you must use the same source code and the
   same optimization options for both compilations. 

   With -fbranch-probabilities, GCC puts a ‘REG_BR_PROB’ note on each ‘JUMP_INSN’
   and ‘CALL_INSN’. These can be used to improve optimization. Currently, they are
   only used in one place: in reorg.c, instead of guessing which path a branch is
   most likely to take, the ‘REG_BR_PROB’ values are used to exactly determine
   which path is taken more often.
```

Comment: GCC != .Net JIT. And it's a bit different, i'm not talking about compile time optimization.

Comment: No, but optimizations will often share names despite differing compilers. Dead code elimination will be called the same regardless.